# Why doesn't my Dart async function start working immediately

Tags: dart, async-await

I have this program that I'm using to learn about Dart's async programming.

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<int> sumStream(Stream<int> stream) async {
  var sum = 0;
  await for (final value in stream) {
    print('consuming event $value');
    sum += value;
  }
  return sum;
}

Stream<int> countStream(int to) async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= to; i++) {
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    print('publishing event $i');
    yield i;
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  var stream = countStream(10);
  var sum = sumStream(stream);

  print('working...');
  sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  print('working...');
  sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  print('working...');
  sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

  print(await sum); // 55
}
```

Output:

```
working...
working...
working...
publishing event 1
consuming event 1
publishing event 2
consuming event 2
publishing event 3
consuming event 3
publishing event 4
consuming event 4
publishing event 5
consuming event 5
publishing event 6
consuming event 6
publishing event 7
consuming event 7
publishing event 8
consuming event 8
publishing event 9
consuming event 9
publishing event 10
consuming event 10
55
```

In the code above, I chose not to `await` for the result of `sumStream()` immediately because I wanted to do some additional work while `sumStream()` is busy consuming events from the provided stream. So my expectation was that `sumStream()` would start running immediately while `main()` is running. I expected the output to look something like below text. I expected the text `working...` to be interleaved with the other print outs from the publisher `countStream()` and the consumer `sumStream()`.

```
working...
publishing event 1
consuming event 1
publishing event 2
consuming event 2
publishing event 3
consuming event 3
working...
publishing event 4
consuming event 4
publishing event 5
consuming event 5
publishing event 6
working...
consuming event 6
publishing event 7
consuming event 7
publishing event 8
consuming event 8
publishing event 9
consuming event 9
publishing event 10
consuming event 10
55
```

Is this because Dart is single threaded and thus it can't run `main()`, `countStream()` and `sumStream()` at the same time?
If so, how could I change my program so that `sumStream()` would run in parallel with `main()` (make it multi-threaded)?

Comment: You don't get the concurrency you expect because the streams won't execute until the event queue is processed, and that won't happen until you use `await` or exit `main`.  And yes, each Dart isolate is single-threaded, so if you want parallel (and not just concurrent) operations, you will need to spawn a separate isolate.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the explanation. After your response and thinking about the program a little more, I understand why it was not behaving the way I expected it to. Also my question was not very clear but I guess you understood it anyway. What I really wanted is to run `main()` while `countStream()` is sleeping and run `countStream()` while `main()` is sleeping. Turns out `sleep()` was blocking the queue and after I replaced it with `await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));` as suggested by @mmcdon20 below, it's working as I like it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is due to the `sleep` function. [Sleep function documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-io/sleep.html):

> Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call.

I suggest trying this instead:

```dart
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

Which won't block the processing of all the other async operations going on.